# Loadrunner 11.52 record chrome with command line switches

Tags: google-chrome, loadrunner

I have side by side chrome installs for testing:

- *version 35*
- *version 13*

To launch *version 13* I have a separate chrome application directory and pass in some command line switches e.g.:

```
--user-data-dir="C:\UserData" --chrome-version=13.0.782.218
```

This works fine, on the desktop I just create a shortcut to the exe and tag on the switches.

How do I do that when I record in Loadrunner?

I can browse to the exe from the "start recording" dialog, but I can't add the switches.

Using the desktop shortcut with the switches doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If your website does not generate chrome specific code then just use any browser for recording

You can always record in proxy mode any HTTP based communication you wish, whether on machine or not.